# Print Button In Excel 2016 Using Macros?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm currently trying to create a Print Button on one of my worksheets.  I need it to print that worksheet as well as another one.  Both of the names are "Budget Sheet" and "Listed Commitments Sheet" without the quotation marks.

I created the **button** without hassle, but I know very little about Macros so I still need the code.  I've tried multiple solutions, but nothing seems to work.  I've recently tried to use this [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDLiX.png), but it hasn't worked.  What am I doing wrong?  What code could I possibly use instead?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Function PrintMultipleSheets()
    Sheets(Array("Budget Sheet", "Listed Commitments Sheet")).PrintOut
End Function

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of an image, can you paste the code here (and format with the code tags, `{}`)? Also, what isn't working, is there an error? Is it just not printing, etc.?

Comment: It comes up with an error that says "Compile Error: Expected End Sub".

Comment: You put a function inside a sub. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: This code can't compile as-is.

Comment: Get ride of the line `Function PrintMultipleSheets()` and get rid of `End Function`. It should work I think.

Comment: @DavidZemens It worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Cheers @Ash do consider marking my answer (below) as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It comes up with an error that says "Compile Error: Expected End Sub".

The code doesn't compile, because you can't have a `Function` *inside* a `Sub`.

Get ride of the line `Function PrintMultipleSheets()` and get rid of `End Function`. It should work I think. You'll end up with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets(Array("Budget Sheet", "Listed Commitments Sheet")).PrintOut

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple loop with a print call:

```
Sub forEachWs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call printSheet(ws)
    Next
End Sub

Function pasteContents(ws as Worksheet)
     ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End Function
```